# %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} variable inside If statement in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

in Apache 2.4.6 (the up-to-date version from CentOS 7 repository) I am trying to pass all the PHP files for processing to a specially compiled PHP-FPM in case that "php7.enable" file is present in the root of the website.

If I try this:

```
<If "-f %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} . '/php7.enable'">
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1" [P]
</If>
```

the condition works, but the %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} on the RewriteRule line is not expanded to the variable value, but is everytime empty. Strange is, that outside the "If" block, the expansion works. 
Does anybody have any idea why and how to make it work ?
Thanks.

Comment: From my understanding of the syntax, I would hve written the condition as `<If "-f '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/php7.enable'">`

Comment: The If statement itself is not a problem it is working. The problem is the variable expansion.
Btw. both my and your syntax works. ;-)

Comment: Maybe my descrption of the issue is not clear enough, the expansion which is not working is on the RewriteRule line. The IF condition itself is working perfectly.

Comment: Just a thought: can't you turn your `<If>` into RewriteCond? (`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/php7.enable -f`)

Comment: Strange..I've just tried the RewriteCond, but it seems that even in this case, the %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} is empty, because the condition is never met... I am using: VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts.php7/%-2.0.%-1.0/%-3+/  in my config.
Could this be the reason of getting the DOCUMENT_ROOT empty ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround which is the solution of my problem:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
 Require all granted
 <If "-f '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/php7.enable'">
   SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001
 </If>
</FilesMatch>
```

so I don't need the DOCUMENT_ROOT value at all and it works perfectly.
If I put "php7.enable" file to the DOCUMENT_ROOT of the website, all PHP files are being interpreted by PHP-FPM (running PHP7). If there's no such file found in the DOCUMENT_ROOT, the Apache handler is used to let the PHP interpret by (OS built-in) PHP5.

Thanks for all the ideas, it helped me to find a way to the root cause of the problem (with VirtualDocumentRoot in the config file the DOCUMENT_ROOT is probably not filled-in correctly).

It can be also seen in this question - [Mass virtual hosting with Apache 2.4](https://serverfault.com/questions/606830/mass-virtual-hosting-with-apache-2-4)